# Segmentation fault (core dumped) adding arrays

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, addition

I'm currently helping my cousin with some homework of his. The homework was to add two large numbers together using arrays, however I've run into an issue. Whenever I run the program, it gives me the "segmentation fault (core dumped)" error. That's typically memory issues but I've tried control the size of my result array with malloc, but without success. Can you spot my mistake?

Source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, j, h;

    int a[] = {0, 4, 5, 9, 2, 7, 4, 9, 5, 7, 1, 6, 2, 0, 3, 0};
    int b[] = {0, 2, 7, 8, 4, 9, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    int *result = (int *) malloc(17*sizeof(int));

    for (i = 1; i < sizeof(result); i++) {   
        if (a[i] + b[i] > 9){
            result[i] = a[i] + b[i] - 10;
            result[i-1] += 1;
        }
        else{
            result[i] = a[i] + b[i];
        }

        for (j = 0; h < sizeof(result); j++) {
            if (result[j] > 9){
                result[j] -= 10;
                result[j-1] += 1;
            }   
        }
    }

    printf("Result: ");
    for (h = 0; h < sizeof(result); h++) {
        printf("%d", result[h]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (i = 1; i < sizeof(result); i++) {` : `i = 0`, `sizeof(result)` is wrong.

Comment: Given that you've got `result[j-1]` and start the loop with `j=0`, you can actually be "underflowing" your array. Put in debug statements: print out `i` and `j` at each stage and see where they go out of range.

Comment: `for (j = 0; h < sizeof(result); j++)` is an infinite loop.

Comment: Alright it's working flawlessly now

Answer (score 1):

In this loop

```
for (j = 0; h < sizeof(result); j++) {
```

you use variable h that was not initialized. So the loop can be for example infinite because the program behaviour in this case is undefined.
Take into account that `sizeof( int * )` is not the same as for example `sizeof( int[17] )`, Usually `sizeof( int * )` is equal to 4 or 8. And result has type `int *`;)

But in any case your code in wrong. You shoud redesign the logic of the program.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommend going from the least significant digit to the most significant digit - that would avoid the O(n^2) complexity.

The problem is the sizeof(result) in the inner loop: sizeof returns the number of bytes occupied by the result array, rather than the number of elements.